# Apple tvOS: Hide subtitles menu option on AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, tvos, http-live-streaming, avkit

When watching a live stream, the subtitles menu option is still present on the video view.
How can I hide the complete subtitles group? If the display should be managed by the m3u8, how must the m3u8 look like that the subtitles menu disappears?

Answer (score 1):

Subtitles are embedded into the HLS stream. AVPlayerViewController defines a property called `allowedSubtitleOptionLanguages` which allows to limit the allowed set of languages supported for the subtitles.

In order to disable completely the subtitles tab you could assign an empty list of allowed languages to that property:

```
playerViewController?.allowedSubtitleOptionLanguages = [""]
```